Quasar SSR Hydration Mismatches because of v-for
I'm utilizing the Quasar framework with Vue and Vite to create a blog for myself. I am attempting to get SSR setup utilizing Quasar's SSR mode. I think for the most part it seems to be working, although on my index page I have a v-for to loop through my published posts to display them on the page.
My prefetch seems to be grabbing the data fine, but I get this warning/error pair:
[Vue warn]: Hydration children mismatch in <div>: server rendered element contains more child nodes than client vdom. 
  at <QPage class="n-page index-page" > 
  at <IndexPage onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <QPageContainer> 
  at <QLayout view="lHh lpR lFf" class="n-background" > 
  at <MainLayout onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App > 
  at <AppWrapper>

Hydration completed but contains mismatches.

I think the issue is the only v-for I have on the page in my <router-link>s for the posts. Here is the page code:
<template>
  <q-page class="n-page index-page">
    <div class="text-h1 text-center">Popular Mission Logs</div>
    <div class="row q-pa-xl pop-logs">
      <q-space />
      <q-card class="popular-log q-pa-lg n-card n-card--important">
        <div class="text-h3">{{ publishedDrafts[0]?.title || '' }}</div>
        <render-markdown
          class="markdown-preview"
          :markdown="
            truncate(publishedDrafts[0]?.markdown || '', { length: 500 })
          "
          flat
        />
      </q-card>
      <q-space />
      <img src="../assets/astro-helmet.svg" class="helmet-img q-pa-sm" />
      <q-space />
    </div>
    <div class="text-h2 recent-logs">Recent Mission Logs</div>
    <div class="cards q-pa-sm">
      <router-link
        v-for="post in publishedDrafts"
        class="card-link"
        :key="post.id"
        :to="{
          name: RouteNames.READ_POST,
          params: {
            postId: post.draft_id,
          },
        }"
      >
        <q-card class="n-card post-card" style="overflow-y: auto">
          <q-card-section class="text-h4">
            {{ post.title }}
          </q-card-section>
          <q-card-section>
            <render-markdown
              class="markdown-preview"
              :markdown="truncate(post.markdown, { length: 200 })"
              flat
            />
          </q-card-section>
        </q-card>
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { truncate } from 'lodash-es';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
import { RenderMarkdown, usePostStore } from 'src/models/post';
import { RouteNames } from 'src/router/routes';
// import { onMounted } from 'vue';

defineOptions({
  preFetch({ store }) {
    const { getPublished } = usePostStore(store);
    const { publishedDrafts } = storeToRefs(usePostStore(store));

    console.log('prefetching published drafts...');
    if (publishedDrafts.value.length === 0) {
      return getPublished();
    }
  },
});

// const { getPublished } = usePostStore();
const { publishedDrafts } = storeToRefs(usePostStore());

// onMounted(async () => {
//   if (publishedDrafts.value.length === 0) {
//     await getPublished();
//   }
// });
</script>

I know this isn't great but it's hard to say exactly what I've tried since I've been fiddling with a lot. I know i tried wrapping my v-for in a v-if to conditionally render it or not, that didn't seem to help.
